# How to make the sum of a range values on a new vector for specific conditions?

Tags: r, loops, sum

How could I to obtain new vectors of cummulative sums following

```
A:
year month day    x   y
               .
               .
               .
2000  10   20     10  0
2000  10   21     2   0
2000  10   22     5   1
2000  10   23     9   0
               .
               .
               .
```

If “y” > 0 then how can I sum the “x” values in these ranges for next mention vectors:

B: sum of x values from the date where y>0 and two days before (5+2+10=17) for all the dates where y>0.

C: sum of x values of 10 days before the two days before an event where y>0, i.e, from 2000-11-10 until 2000-10-20, for all the dates where y>0. In this case, 2000-10-22 is y>0, then it was grouped and summarized the 10 days before 2 days before the event where y>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your first question, here is one idea. We can create a column called `Flag` showing the rows meeting the condition. In the following code, `A2` is the intermediate data frame with the `Flag` column. `Flag == 1` indicates the rows `y > 0` and the previous two rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A2 <- A %>%
  mutate(Flag1 = ifelse(y > 0, 1, NA)) %>%
  mutate(Flag2 = lead(Flag1, 2)) %>%
  fill(Flag1, .direction = "up") %>%
  fill(Flag2, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(Flag = Flag1 + Flag2 - 1) 
A2
#   year month day  x y Flag1 Flag2 Flag
# 1 2000    10  20 10 0     1     1    1
# 2 2000    10  21  2 0     1     1    1
# 3 2000    10  22  5 1     1     1    1
# 4 2000    10  23  9 0    NA     1   NA
```

After that, we can filter for `Flag == 1` and calculate the sum using `summarise`. `A3` is the final output.

```
A3 <- A2 %>%
  filter(Flag == 1) %>%
  summarise(x_sum = sum(x))
A3
#   x_sum
# 1    17
```

As for your second question, since you did not provide a good example dataset and at least to me it is not clear what do you want. I will not try to answer that right now. If you can provide proper updates, I may try to think about it.

**DATA**

```
A <- read.table(text = "year month day    x   y
                2000  10   20     10  0
                2000  10   21     2   0
                2000  10   22     5   1
                2000  10   23     9   0",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```